# object object from get_userProfileProperties() stringify

Tags: javascript, user-profile, user, user-profile-property, json

```
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user properties for the target user.
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
    // getMyProperties method.
    MyProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(MyProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getMyNewsChoicesSuccess, getMyNewsChoicesFail);
    },

    getMyNewsChoicesSuccess = function () {
        //get the news choice by actually fieldname
        var MyChoices = (MyProperties.get_userProfileProperties());
        $('#NBStest').text(MyChoices);

    },
```

My code here works however it returns [object object] when I add `JSON.stringify` it returns

```
{"UserProfile_GUID":"134ebf5f-4b97-464b-8362-a1ea699df676","SID":"S-1-5-21-516259181-3605073475-84029850-3763","ADGuid":"","AccountName":"main\\dah","FirstName":"Dave","SPS-PhoneticFirstName":"","LastName":"Horsley","SPS-PhoneticLastName":"","PreferredName":"Dave Horsley","SPS-PhoneticDisplayName":"","WorkPhone":"","Department":"Developers"}
```

If I then did JSON.parse it returns [object object] again. just need away of getting whats in my array/key value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties.userProfileProperties property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679700(v=office.15).aspx) returns an *a dictionary of property name keys and their string values*.

In JavaScript you could use the following syntax to access value in a dictionary:

```
myProperties.get_userProfileProperties().UserName
```

or

```
myProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['UserName']
```

### Example

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
var myProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
context.load(myProperties);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() { 
      console.log('User Name:' + myProperties.get_userProfileProperties().UserName);
   },
    function(sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```